# Pull child objects with all of their dependencies when lazy loading enbabled in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When I am loading an object that has children objects, I use the syntax of  environmentQuery.Include("Sites");  The problem is that when the sites get pulled with the context, they have children objects that I also need to include, but do not by default. How can I, or how do I accomplish this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load children of `Sites` you'd add another include:

```
.Include("Sites.ChildOfSites")
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the late disclosing of this answer. That is what I came across eventually, and worked great.